# Flash CS5 -- text starting in the middle automatically

Tags: flash, text, input

I'm trying to make a simple program that manipulates data input by users by changing it into a format that a later project will decode and re-manipulate for a jeopardy-type game.

I'm running into what is probably a VERY simple fix, but I can't find it.

When I create my text box and start typing, it automatically has 3 lines instead of just one, as if I've already started typing and pressed enter two times. I've checked to make sure that there wasn't already text inside of the box before running it, checked every option inside of the text properties thoroughly and googled ones that had functions that were unknown to me, tried searching google for help, tried searching here for help, and various other things that would seem like a small mistake. The closest thing I found was the exact opposite: [Flash vertical text alignment in middle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1568181/flash-vertical-text-alignment-in-middle)

It isn't just one text box -- it's every one of them in my program.

I know I could probably run some AS3 code to fix it, but I would rather not have to resort to all of that, as it's supposed to be just a simple little program.

Example:

---

- Line 1 <--- where I would like text to start
- Line 2
- Line 3 <--- where text starts
- Line 4
- etc

  ---

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Edit 1: Forgot to add that the textbox is multiline (obviously, but in case someone didn't know)

Comment: Can you post a sample FLA somewhere?

Comment: Just the swf would work, too.  But unless we can somehow check what's going on, there's just no way to tell why this happens.

Answer (score 0):

You could empty the textfield when someone clicks on the textfield:

```
 myTextField.addEventListener(FocusEvent.FOCUS_IN, onFocusIn);

 private function onFocusIn(e:FocusEvent):void {
     myTextField.text = ""
     // this is triggered when you click your mouse or tab to the textfield where you would start typing
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I'd like to find another, non-actionscript way, if there is one. However, if I must, I will resort to that option. :)

Comment: you're really going to be hard pressed to continue with any flash project without using actionscript at some point, but... to totally clear a textfield (or reset a movieclip, or anything similar), you can always just add a blank keyframe before it, then do a gotoAndStop or gotoAndPlay to get to the frame with your textfield and it should be totally reset.

Comment: or put your textfield inside of a movieclip on frame 2 with a blank keyframe on frame 1, then right before you want it to be cleared tell your movieclip myClip.gotoAndStop(2)